# Java kill or terminate a thread

Tags: java, concurrency

Hi all:
Basically I need to kill or stop a thread running when user press a Terminate button. This thread loop through a arraylist and display each event on JTextArea. The requirement is when user press the Terminate button, I need to terminate the running thread and at the same time ADD a new "Terminating" event to the arraylist and let it run again to print "Programing terminating". The following code kind of "works", but I got a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in the console. Anyone can help?

```
public void startEvents()
    {
        terminate = false;
        worker = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Iterator<Event> it = eventList.iterator();

                while (it.hasNext())
                {
                    waitWhileSuspended();
                    terminatEvents();
                    Event ev = it.next();
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(ev.getDelayTime());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1)
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    jTextArea.append(ev.toString() + "\n");
                    it.remove();
                }
                jbStart.setEnabled(true);
                jmiStart.setEnabled(true);
                jbRestart.setEnabled(true);
                jmiRestart.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        worker.start();
    }
public void terminatEvents()
    {
        while(terminate)
        {
            Thread.yield();
            eventList.clear();
            eventList.add(new Terminate(delayTime));
            startEvents();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What data type is eventList? (is is actually a java.util.ArrayList<...>)  Try a collection in the java.util.concurrent package and see if that helps.  Just an FYI I usually use a mutex of some sort  (e.g. java.util.concurrent.ReentrantLock) for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are modifying a List and at the same time looping over it. With standard Lists the behaviour of this is undefined and this throws the Exception.
Have a look at the [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package for collections that are safe for multi threaded use.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are modifying the list (clearing it then adding a new `Terminate` event) while iterating on it. That's why you get the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

I would advise you to simply have a `terminate()` method in your thread object, and call it to stop printing event the list THEN print the new `Terminate` event, without using the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a changing of Collection from 2 threads. By default, collections are unsynchronized, you should use "Synchronized" keyword or switch to  synchronizedCollection http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)

Comment: I suspected that the sychronized may be the solution. Can anyone tell me how I should implement it in my code.

Comment: @user528995, please show, how do you declare and init you eventList

Comment: This is wrong.  The exception occurs on a single thread and in fact has nothing to do with threading.  The name is a misnomer.  It is in fact as several others have said, the underlying list is being changed while you are at the same time iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to stop a thread is to set some volatile boolean flag, I see that in your case it is the `terminate` field. To follow the normal pattern, you should just check this flag on each iteration like `while (!terminated && ...)`. The thread that sets the terminate flag should also put your final event in some field, say, terminateEvent which you should check after the loop if terminate is true at that point (that is, if the thread was terminated as opposed to finishing normally). Of course, access to terminateEvent should be synchronized (note that volatile probably won't work here).

However, since you have a list of events to process, I would rather follow another pattern. Replace the list with a concurrent queue (LinkedBlockingQueue is a good example) and then, when you need to terminate the thread, instead of setting a boolean flag you just clear the queue and put your termination event there. The event processing thread, after processing each event, should check if that was a termination event (by using instanceof or some sort of getEventClass() method) and if it was, just break the loop.

Note that since your thread has lengthy operations like Thread.sleep() and possibly waitWhileSuspended() (whatever it is, although you may not need it any more after switching to a blocking queue), you need to interrupt() your thread after placing the termination event into the queue, and handle InterruptedException in the event processing thread accordingly to the application logic. For example, you should decide whether to process an event if Thread.sleep() was interrupted or maybe continue to the next iteration instead.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is

```
public void run() {
  while (!isInterrupted()) {
    // actual working code goes here
  }
} // end of life for this thread
```

and then just call interrupt() when I want to stop the thread.